# How bad is polynomial regression with OLS

Tags: inverse, numerical-linear-algebra, regression, least-squares, condition-number

Let us look at the following polynomial regression:
$$
y_{i} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_{i} + \beta_{2}x_{i}^{2} + \dots + \beta_{m}x_{i}^{m} + \varepsilon_{i}.
$$
Then, OLS solution is given by
$$
\hat{\mathbf{\beta}} = (\mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{y}
$$
and the covariance matrix is
$$
\Sigma= \sigma (\mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{X})^{-1}.
$$
Therefore, we have to compute the inverse of the product of Vandermonde matrix $\mathbf{X}$.

I can not understand how will it affect the estimator of $\beta$ and the estimator of the covariance matrix $\Sigma$. How big problem is it?

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me. What affects the estimators and might be a problem?

Comment: this is what I can not understand... Does "bad" mean that it will be very sensitive to the data vector $y$ no matter how much data we have?

Answer (score 0):

How 'bad' depends on the degree of your polynomial, and the basis of choice. Usually, the "standard basis" of $\{1, x, x^2, \dots, x^m\}$, as you suggested, is the *worst* basis you could try for several reasons:

1. The feature matrix of high-degree standard basis polynomials (also known as the Vandermonde matrix) is *extremely* ill conditioned
2. Polynomials described according to the standard basis are extremely hard to regularize. Regular L2 regularization, as in Ridge regression, doesn't help.

I think the default go-to basis is the Bernstein basis. See [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/560625/360265) answer on stats.stackexchange. However, note that you first need to normalize all your $x$ values to lie between zero and one (or some other interval, but they all have to lie in an interval).